# Run functionality on splash screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I want to run functionality (call functions) when app is launched in React Native.

When app is launched there is the splash screen (default), it loads the app for a few seconds and then reads the `index.js` root file to render the app.

I can't find a way to run my own functionality during this loading state of the app and as long as my functionality did not resolve showing the splash screen of React Native.

Any solutions / ideas?

Comment: You can use a third-party library like [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen). That way you can close the splash screen whenever you want. https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#usage Note: this will not work with expo managed apps since you need to add native code. But you can use [Expo SplashScreen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should address the needs of basically anyone who wants to create animated splash screens, or start some loading procedures during the splash screen.
The basic version does not need any extra packages, however, it assumes you are using `React Navigation 5.x`, or a similar solution for screen-based navigation.

I have left code in the comments for those who wish to use `expo-splash-screen` (or similar packages). It is used to make sure that the static splash screen remains visible until the entire application tree has finished the initial rendering - otherwise, a brief flash will appear while the static splash screen is hidden, but the application tree has not finished mounting by that time.

```
import React from "react";
import { Animated, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
// import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

/*
    Call this function here such that the static splash remains visible
    before rendering any component in the App tree.
*/
// SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync().catch((error) => {
//  // While developing, this function will be called multiple times,
//  // at times when the static splash screen is already hidden.
//  // Thus, it will reject with an error.
//  // You can safely ignore that error and move on with real business.
    
//  // console.warn("SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync error:", error);
// });


const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render = () => {
        return <Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
            <Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
            <Screen name="HelloWorld" component={HelloWorldScreen} />
        </Navigator>;
    }
}


class SplashScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    state = { currentProgress: 0 };
    progress = new Animated.Value(0);
    progressStyle = [
        styles.progressBar,
        { width: this.progress.interpolate(PROGRESS_INTERPOLATION) }
    ];

    setStateAsync = setStateAsync.bind(this);

    animateProgressBar = (toValue = 0) => {
        Animated.timing(this.progress, {
            toValue,
            duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
            isInteraction: false,
            useNativeDriver: false // Layout props are not supported by Animated module
        }).start();
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // If you're using Expo SplashScreen, uncomment the code below
        // to hide the static splash screen.

        // SplashScreen.hideAsync().catch((error) => {
        //  // While developing, this function will be called multiple times,
        //  // at times when the static splash screen is already hidden.
        //  // Thus, it will reject with an error.
        //  // You can safely ignore that error and move on with real business.
        //
        //  // console.warn("SplashScreen.hideAsync error:", error);
        // });
        
        // Start your loading procedure here
        this.doSomething()
            .then(() => { return this.setStateAsync({ currentProgress: 15 }); })
            .then(() => { return this.doSomething(); })
            .then(() => { return this.setStateAsync({ currentProgress: 35 }); })
            .then(() => { return this.doSomething(); })
            .then(() => { return this.setStateAsync({ currentProgress: 70 }); })
            .then(() => { return this.doSomething(); })
            .then(() => { return this.setStateAsync({ currentProgress: 100 }); })
            // Allow the progress bar to visibly animate to 100%
            .then(() => { return setTimeoutAsync(ANIMATION_DURATION + EXTRA_DELAY_TO_100_PERCENT); })
            // Once all loading tasks are finished, navigate to your next screen
            .then(() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("HelloWorld"); })
            // Make sure the following never occurs in production
            .catch((startupError) => { console.error("An error occurred during startup", startupError); });
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
        const { currentProgress } = this.state;

        if (currentProgress !== prevState.currentProgress) {
            // Passively react to currentProgress changes
            // and animate the progress bar accordingly
            this.animateProgressBar(currentProgress);
        }
    }

    render = () => {
        return <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
                <Animated.View style={this.progressStyle} />
            </View>
        </View>;
    }
}


class HelloWorldScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    render = () => { return <Text>Hello, world!</Text>; }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 50
    },
    progressContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 10
    },
    progressBar: {
        // width set by animation
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        borderRadius: 5,
        overflow: "hidden"
    }
});

const PROGRESS_INTERPOLATION = {
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: ["0%", "100%"],

    // if the input is outside the range 0-100, clamps the output to specified outputRange values
    extrapolate: "clamp"
};

const ANIMATION_DURATION = 200; // milliseconds
const EXTRA_DELAY_TO_100_PERCENT = 50; // milliseconds


/*
    Helper functions that allow to easily work with async functions
*/

// Promisify React.Component's setState method
// Remember to .bind(this) in the class you use it
function setStateAsync(state = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try { this.setState(state, resolve); }
        catch (error) { reject(error); }
    });
}

// Promisify setTimeout
function setTimeoutAsync(timeout = 1000){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try { setTimeout(resolve, timeout); }
        catch (error) { reject(error); }
    })
}

// Dummy method that simulates some loading delay, 0-1000 milliseconds
function doSomething() { return setTimeoutAsync(Math.random() * 1000); }
```